# Как вывести в консоль данные sql таблицы с помощью hql запроса?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, hql

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.github.steed777</groupId>
    <artifactId>HQLInquiry</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.firebirdsql.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaybird-jdk18</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>18.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20190722</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security.oauth/spring-security-oauth2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security.oauth.boot/spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

```html
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=55606:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\IdeaProjects\HQLInquiry\target\classes;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\firebirdsql\jdbc\jaybird-jdk18\2.2.15\jaybird-jdk18-2.2.15.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\javax\resource\connector-api\1.5\connector-api-1.5.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\antlr\antlr-runtime\3.4\antlr-runtime-3.4.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\antlr\stringtemplate\3.2.1\stringtemplate-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.2.1.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-web-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.2.1.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.2.1.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.3\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.3\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.12.1\log4j-to-slf4j-2.12.1.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.12.1\log4j-api-2.12.1.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.29\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.29.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\1.3.5\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.25\snakeyaml-1.25.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.2.1.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-json-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.10.0\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.10.0\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.10.0\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.2.1.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.27\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.27\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.27.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.27\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.27.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-validation\2.2.1.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-validation-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\jakarta\validation\jakarta.validation-api\2.0.1\jakarta.validation-api-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\validator\hibernate-validator\6.0.18.Final\hibernate-validator-6.0.18.Final.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.2.1.RELEASE\spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.2.1.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.2.1.RELEASE\spring-aop-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.2.1.RELEASE\spring-expression-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf\2.2.2.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\thymeleaf-spring5\3.0.11.RELEASE\thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\thymeleaf\3.0.11.RELEASE\thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\attoparser\attoparser\2.0.5.RELEASE\attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\unbescape\unbescape\1.1.6.RELEASE\unbescape-1.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\extras\thymeleaf-extras-java8time\3.0.4.RELEASE\thymeleaf-extras-java8time-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\2.2.2.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\2.2.1.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-aop-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.4\aspectjweaver-1.9.4.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\2.2.1.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\3.4.1\HikariCP-3.4.1.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\jakarta\activation\jakarta.activation-api\1.2.1\jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\jakarta\persistence\jakarta.persistence-api\2.2.3\jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\jakarta\transaction\jakarta.transaction-api\1.3.3\jakarta.transaction-api-1.3.3.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.4.8.Final\hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.4.1.Final\jboss-logging-3.4.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.24.0-GA\javassist-3.24.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.10.2\byte-buddy-1.10.2.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.0.5.Final\jandex-2.0.5.Final.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.5.1\classmate-1.5.1.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\dom4j\dom4j\2.1.1\dom4j-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.1.0.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\2.2.1.RELEASE\spring-data-jpa-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\5.2.1.RELEASE\spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\5.2.1.RELEASE\spring-aspects-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\2.3.2\jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.2.1.RELEASE\spring-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.2.1.RELEASE\spring-jcl-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\jetbrains\annotations\18.0.0\annotations-18.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\json\json\20190722\json-20190722.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\flywaydb\flyway-core\4.1.2\flyway-core-4.1.2.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jdbc\1.1.5.RELEASE\spring-data-jdbc-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-relational\1.1.1.RELEASE\spring-data-relational-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\2.2.1.RELEASE\spring-data-commons-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\5.2.1.RELEASE\spring-tx-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.2.1.RELEASE\spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.2.1.RELEASE\spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\5.2.1.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.29\slf4j-api-1.7.29.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\oauth\spring-security-oauth2\2.4.0.RELEASE\spring-security-oauth2-2.4.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-core\5.2.1.RELEASE\spring-security-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-config\5.2.1.RELEASE\spring-security-config-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-web\5.2.1.RELEASE\spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.13\commons-codec-1.13.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\oauth\boot\spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure\2.2.5.RELEASE\spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.10.0\jackson-annotations-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.10.0\jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.10.0\jackson-core-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\javax\xml\bind\jaxb-api\2.3.1\jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\javax\activation\javax.activation-api\1.2.0\javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.2.1.RELEASE\spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.2.1.RELEASE\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-jwt\1.0.11.RELEASE\spring-security-jwt-1.0.11.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\bouncycastle\bcpkix-jdk15on\1.64\bcpkix-jdk15on-1.64.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\bouncycastle\bcprov-jdk15on\1.64\bcprov-jdk15on-1.64.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.2\jaxb-runtime-2.3.2.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\2.3.2\txw2-2.3.2.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\3.0.8\istack-commons-runtime-3.0.8.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\org\jvnet\staxex\stax-ex\1.8.1\stax-ex-1.8.1.jar;C:\Users\Senko_KL\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\fastinfoset\FastInfoset\1.2.16\FastInfoset-1.2.16.jar" Main

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.1.RELEASE)

2020-03-03 14:22:16.670  INFO 7392 --- [           main] Main                                     : Starting Main on RUMSCWS207 with PID 7392 (C:\Users\Senko_KL\IdeaProjects\HQLInquiry\target\classes started by Senko_KL in C:\Users\Senko_KL\IdeaProjects\HQLInquiry)
2020-03-03 14:22:16.680  INFO 7392 --- [           main] Main                                     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-03-03 14:22:16.924  WARN 7392 --- [           main] ionWarningsApplicationContextInitializer : 

** WARNING ** : Your ApplicationContext is unlikely to start due to a @ComponentScan of the default package.


2020-03-03 14:25:52.359  WARN 7392 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [Main]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.introspection.ReactiveOpaqueTokenIntrospector]
2020-03-03 14:25:52.372  INFO 7392 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-03-03 14:25:52.378 ERROR 7392 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [Main]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.introspection.ReactiveOpaqueTokenIntrospector]
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:184) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:325) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:242) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
 at Main.main(Main.java:17) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.introspection.ReactiveOpaqueTokenIntrospector]
 at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:327) ~[spring-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.adapt(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:483) ~[spring-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.getValue(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:403) ~[spring-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.asMap(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:288) ~[spring-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.core.annotation.AbstractMergedAnnotation.asAnnotationAttributes(AbstractMergedAnnotation.java:193) ~[spring-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotatedTypeMetadata.java:106) ~[spring-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils.attributesFor(AnnotationConfigUtils.java:285) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.determineBeanNameFromAnnotation(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:100) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.generateBeanName(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:79) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:280) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:132) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:290) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:202) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:170) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
 ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.introspection.ReactiveOpaqueTokenIntrospector
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
 at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:277) ~[spring-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:317) ~[spring-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
 ... 27 common frames omitted
```

Пытаюсь вывести в консоль данные sql таблицы с помощью hql запроса, не могу сообразить как...
Вот мой код (класс `Main`):

```
import model.Lawyers;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import service.LawyersService;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {
    private static LawyersService lawyersService;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (Lawyers lawyers: lawyersService.findForExport()
             ) {
            System.out.println(lawyers.toString());
        }
        //SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

При запуске возникает `NullPointerException`.

Остальной код ниже:

LawyersRepos:

```
package repos;

import model.Lawyers;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;
@Transactional
public interface LawyersRepos extends JpaRepository<Lawyers, Long> {

    @Query("select e from LAWYERS e where e.version = (select max(b.version) from LAWYERS b where e.id = b.id)")
    List<Lawyers> findLawyerByMaxVersion();
}
```

ApplicationConfig:

```
package config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:hibernate.properties")
class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        return builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan("com.github.steed777");
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {

        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return txManager;
    }
}
```

Lawyers:

LawyersService:

```
package service;

import model.Lawyers;

import java.util.List;

public interface LawyersService {

    List<Lawyers> findAll();
    List<Lawyers> findForExport();
}
```

LawyersServiceImpl:

```
package service.impl;


import model.Lawyers;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import repos.LawyersRepos;
import service.LawyersService;

import java.util.List;



@Service
public class LawyersServiceImpl implements LawyersService {

    private LawyersRepos lawyerRepository;

@Autowired
    public void setLawyerRepository(LawyersRepos lawyerRepository) {
        this.lawyerRepository = lawyerRepository;
    }
    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Lawyers> findAll() {
        return lawyerRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Lawyers> findForExport() {
            List<Lawyers> lawyers = lawyerRepository.findLawyerByMaxVersion();

            return lawyers;
    }
}
```

Comment: А где в этом коде выводятся данные таблицы? И что происходит не так?

Comment: В том то и дело что мне и нужен фрагмент кода, выводящий данные...

Comment: Я сделал так, когда пытался вывести сам:

Comment: import model.Lawyers;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import service.LawyersService;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {
    private static LawyersService lawyersService;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (Lawyers lawyers: lawyersService.findForExport()
             ) {
            System.out.println(lawyers.toString());
        }
        //SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
    }

Comment: Попытка решения это хорошо. Только в комментариях это неудобно читать. Добавьте свой код в вопрос (под ним есть кнопка «править») и расскажите что получилось.

Comment: При попытке запуска кода выходит исключение: NullPointerException

Comment: Покажите POM.xml. Или попробуйте в него добавить зависимость: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client/2.2.5.RELEASE

Comment: Так что получилось в итоге?

Comment: Спасибо, что приняли ответ. Но если он не решил Вашу проблему, то лучше дождаться решения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Используйте [@Autowired](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) чтобы Spring инициализировал `lawyersService`.
2. Чтобы код сработал при запуске приложения реализуйте [`CommandLineRunner`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/CommandLineRunner.html)

Должно получиться что-то вроде этого (код не тестировал):

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main  implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    LawyersService lawyersService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        for (Lawyers lawyers: lawyersService.findForExport()) {
            System.out.println(lawyers);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но все равно не работает :) Выводятся все новые и новые исключения- ConfigurationClassParser.java:184

Comment: @Konstantin Да, побочные явления неизбежны когда в вопросе много кода :) Добавьте сведения об ошибке в конец вопроса.